# yii2 framework: Controller/Action url & without parameters

Tags: php, mysql, yii

In my application , I have AdminController with actionupdate, So in **`YII`** the path becomes **`admin/update`**. Now in order to get certain users info , I use the following path **`admin/update?id=10 where 10`** is the **`empID`**.

Is there any way to do the same thing without id part of the path, i.e. I want my path to look like admin/update? instead of (**`admin/update?id=10`**). i don't need the user want to see the id values.

Thank you!

Comment: but that's admin who will see id, not user

Comment: you can use ajax to send post, or in Yii2 you can also use pjax.

Comment: instead of `admin/update?id=10` this, you can pass value in encrypted form like - `admin/update?req=xdTy728HdkLd` decrypt same into action function.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data using POST method instead of GET

With the help of javascript
Use an hidden form with post method and a input field. onclick of update button set id to input field and submit form. you will get id in controller's action without showing it in url

Answer (score -1):

use in actionUpdata `Yii::$app->user->id;`

```
public function actionUpdate() {
  $empID = Yii::$app->user->id;
}
```